# Myob Odbc insert

Tags: odbc, myob

Are there any functions/queries using MYOB ODBC to query the ID from MYOB Sale after doing INSERT ?

For example we can do SCOPE_IDENTITY() in SQL Server to get the ID value after performing INSERT operation. But are there any using MYOB ODBC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Behind the scenes the ODBC Driver is effectively just automating the manual MYOB import process. The best you could do is to query the database again to get the last invoice (but that is going to be problematic in a multi-user environment) or some other criteria to identify the invoice you've just inserted.

This should change in the next few months with the release of the API for MYOB AccountRight Live but until then, ODBC is what you're stuck with.

Mick